# Oracle Form FRM-40508 Unable to insert the record

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, oracleforms

I have a Form, and I create a trigger pre-insert in the data block

```
select Investor_Seq.nextval into :INVESTOR.INVESTOR_NUMBER from dual;
```

all the data is valid, 
I only use two trigger, PRE-INSERT AND WHEN BUTTON IS PRESS

press save button:

> FRM-40508 Unable to insert the record

i am using the save button the trigger WHEN BUTTON IS PRESS:

```
commit_FORM;
```

it seem the PRE-INSERT statment error? but the new Investor number is show up on the text item.

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ORCL5_10"."INVESTOR"."INVESTOR_NUMBER")

SQL statment ERROR
INSERT INTO INVESTOR (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,STREET_ADDRESS,CITY,PROVINCE,POSTAL_CODE,
AREA_CODE,PHONE_NUMBER,EMAIL_ADDRESS,ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the column list of the `INSERT` statement, you'll see that `investor_number` isn't among those columns.

It means that - although `PRE-INSERT` trigger fetched the next sequence value into a field on the screen, it is **not** part of that table. I guess that its *database column* property isn't correctly set, i.e. that form field doesn't belong to the `investor` table.

Should be easy to fix; inspect `:investor.investor_number` field's property palette and *map* it to the table column.